# "No students are athletes" but "some teachers are both athletes and students"

Tags: puzzle

I was reading some logical test [here](https://www.practice4me.com/logical-reasoning-test-examples/). I reported it down below

> Given the following premises, state whether the conclusions are true,
> false, or unknown:
>
> All athletes are coaches, but not all coaches are athletes. All
> coaches live in Chicago. No students are athletes, but all students
> are coaches. Some teachers are both athletes and students. Some
> parents are teachers, but no parents are students or athletes.
>
> 4. All parents live in Chicago.
>
> A) True
>
> B) False
>
> C) Uncertain
>
> 5. All coaches are students.
>
> A) True
>
> B) False
>
> C) Uncertain

however if "No students are athletes", I don't understand how "some teachers are both athletes and students".

Comment: The premises, as you observed, are inconsistent. Maybe the intention of the text is now to conclude that everything is true using the principle of explosion (ex falso sequitur quodlibet).

Comment: I agree with your puzzlement... In addition, to say that "some teachers are student" sounds very strange.

Comment: @Magdiragdag. actually they say that 4)->uncertain and 5)->false. I think the test is just wrong...

Comment: The depicted Venn diagram "depicts" a different premise: "Some teachers are either athletes or students".

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, yes I agree with you

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA The Venn diagram also seems to suggest all teachers are coaches, but this is not obvious to me and may not matter. What does matter for 5 to be false is that there is at least one non-student coach, which would be satisfied by there being at least one athlete, and that depends on words. *"Some teachers are athletes and some teachers are students"* would work, suggesting the original used *both* in a non-standard way

Comment: It could be that the statement is intended to mean the following: "Some teachers are athletes and some teachers are students."